# How to toggle the children of a list item with a specific class

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

How can I use jQuery to `.toggle` the `sub-menu` of a `li` with a class of `menu-item` after the user clicks on the parent `li`. The menu follows this pattern:

```
   <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Click Here To Toggle Child UL</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu"><!-- Toggle all this -->
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="..">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="..">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul><!-- Toggle all this -->
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item Without Children</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I know I need to check if the `li` with a class of `menu-item` has a `ul` child with a class of `sub-menu`, if so then toggle that `ul`. But I dont know how it would be best to write the code for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following using jQuery library:

```
$('.menu > .menu-item:has(ul) > a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GGg44/3/

Comment: would it not be best to have the selector check if it has a ul sibling so the click is not bound to all the `a` links. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes probably. It will save some milliseconds on removing calls from all menu items. Updated the sample.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, it was quite educational.

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault or return false to not activate your default action on your anchor elements:

http://jsbin.com/itegun/edit#javascript,html,live